# Como mostrar diferentes datos relacionados en un DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

estoy intentando mostrar los TOP 10 artistas, con su cancion y su mejor posicion en la lista. El problema es que no se como empezar. Toda ayuda es agradecida

`ESTO SON LOS DATOS DE EL DF`

```
      date     rank   song    artist    last-week     peak-rank.    weeks-on-board
0   2021-11-06  1   Easy On Me  Adele   1.0 1   3
1   2021-11-06  2   Stay    The Kid LAROI & Justin Bieber   2.0 1   16
2   2021-11-06  3   Industry Baby   Lil Nas X & Jack Harlow 3.0 1   14
3   2021-11-06  4   Fancy Like  Walker Hayes    4.0 3   19
4   2021-11-06  5   Bad Habits  Ed Sheeran  5.0 2   18
5   2021-11-06  6   Way 2 Sexy  Drake Featuring Future & Young Thug 6.0 1   8
6   2021-11-06  7   Shivers Ed Sheeran  9.0 7   7
7   2021-11-06  8   Good 4 U    Olivia Rodrigo  7.0 1   24
8   2021-11-06  9   Need To Know    Doja Cat    11.0    9   20
9   2021-11-06  10  Levitating  Dua Lipa    8.0 2   56
```

`El DataFrame tiene mas columnas, 33.000 para ser exactos`

lo que yo quiero es conseguir el top 10 de artistas, con sus respectivas canciones y su mejor posicion en la lista.

Comment: Qué has intentado hasta el momento? Te recomiendo que leas [ask] y [example] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Recuerda que debes compartir el código de lo que has intentado y el error que estás obteniendo. Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que quieres basicamente es ordenar un dataframe en base al valor de una (o varias) columnas, seleccionar ciertas filas en función al valor de una columna (`rank`); y filtrar el dataframe para quedarte con un subconjunto de sus columnas.

```
columnas_interes = [
    'rank',
    'artist',
    'song',
    'peak_rank'
]
# df: el dataframe que adjuntas en la pregunta
df_filtrado = df.query("rank > 0 and rank <= 10").sort_values('rank', ascending=False)[columnas_interes].copy()
# el .copy() puedes ignorarlo si no quieres hacer operaciones/modificaciones en el df_filtrado
```

En primer lugar, el método `query()` permite ejecutar filtros contenidos en un `string`. En este caso le digo que quiero aquellas filas cuyo `rank` esté entre 1 y 10. Este método sería equivalente a llamar a `df.loc[(df['rank'] > 0) & (df['rank'] <= 10)]`.

El método `sort_values()` recibe una o varias columnas como clave para ordenar. Mediante el `ascending=False` le indicamos que queremos que el orden de esa columna sea descendente (de mayor a menor).

Por último, `dataframe[columnas]` lo que hace es filtrar el df para quedarse con las columnas de la lista pasada.

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [answer]. Cuando las preguntas no cumplen con los lineamientos es mejor no responderlas ya que incitan a usuarios a únicamente solicitar ayuda sin hacer ningún esfuerzo y ese no es el propósito del sitio. Saludos